# Calculating Euclidian Norm in Pytorch.. Trouble understanding an implementation

Tags: python, pytorch, euclidean-distance

I've seen another StackOverflow thread talking about the various implementations for calculating the Euclidian norm and I'm having trouble seeing why/how a particular implementation works.

The code is found in an implementation of the MMD metric: https://github.com/josipd/torch-two-sample/blob/master/torch_two_sample/statistics_diff.py

Here is some beginning boilerplate:

```
import torch
sample_1, sample_2 = torch.ones((10,2)), torch.zeros((10,2))
```

Then the next part is where we pick up from the code above.. I'm unsure why the samples are being concatenated together..

```
sample_12 = torch.cat((sample_1, sample_2), 0)
distances = pdist(sample_12, sample_12, norm=2)
```

and are then passed to the pdist function:

```
def pdist(sample_1, sample_2, norm=2, eps=1e-5):
    r"""Compute the matrix of all squared pairwise distances.
    Arguments
    ---------
    sample_1 : torch.Tensor or Variable
        The first sample, should be of shape ``(n_1, d)``.
    sample_2 : torch.Tensor or Variable
        The second sample, should be of shape ``(n_2, d)``.
    norm : float
        The l_p norm to be used.
    Returns
    -------
    torch.Tensor or Variable
        Matrix of shape (n_1, n_2). The [i, j]-th entry is equal to
        ``|| sample_1[i, :] - sample_2[j, :] ||_p``."""
```

here we get to the meat of the calculation

```
    n_1, n_2 = sample_1.size(0), sample_2.size(0)
    norm = float(norm)
    if norm == 2.:
        norms_1 = torch.sum(sample_1**2, dim=1, keepdim=True)
        norms_2 = torch.sum(sample_2**2, dim=1, keepdim=True)
        norms = (norms_1.expand(n_1, n_2) +
             norms_2.transpose(0, 1).expand(n_1, n_2))
        distances_squared = norms - 2 * sample_1.mm(sample_2.t())
        return torch.sqrt(eps + torch.abs(distances_squared))
```

I am at a loss for why the euclidian norm would be calculated this way. Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's walk through this block of code step by step. The definition of Euclidean distance, i.e., L2 norm is

[image]

Let's consider the simplest case. We have two samples,

[image]

Sample `a` has two vectors `[a00, a01]` and `[a10, a11]`. Same for sample `b`. Let first calculate the `norm`

```
n1, n2 = a.size(0), b.size(0)  # here both n1 and n2 have the value 2
norm1 = torch.sum(a**2, dim=1)
norm2 = torch.sum(b**2, dim=1)
```

Now we get

[image]

Next, we have `norms_1.expand(n_1, n_2)` and `norms_2.transpose(0, 1).expand(n_1, n_2)`

[image]

Note that `b` is transposed. The sum of the two gives `norm`

[image]

`sample_1.mm(sample_2.t())`, that's the multiplication of the two matrix.

[image]

Therefore, after the operation

```
distances_squared = norms - 2 * sample_1.mm(sample_2.t())
```

you get

[image]

In the end, the last step is taking the square root of every element in the matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This is one of the most helpful breakdowns I've ever seen :)